# iOS: Feather with glow/shadow effect on uiimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics, shadow

I am trying to find a way to apply feather effect with shadow around the `UIImage`, not `UIImageView` I have in iOS, I couldn't find any perfect solution yet. I have an idea that it might be done by masking, but I am very new to `CoreGraphics`.

If anyone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far and what issues you are having.

Comment: I have no idea what should I try, thats why I have asked the question.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so:
  I was looking for same thing, but unfortunately with no luck.
I decided to create my own feather(ing) code.

add this code to the `UIImage` extension, and then call `[image featherImageWithDepth:4]`, 4 is just example.
Try to keep depth as low as possible.

```
//==============================================================================


- (UIImage*)featherImageWithDepth:(int)featherDepth {

    // First get the image into your data buffer
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);


    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    NSUInteger byteIndex = 0;



    NSUInteger rawDataCount = width*height;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < rawDataCount ; ++i, byteIndex += bytesPerPixel) {

        NSInteger alphaIndex = byteIndex + 3;

        if (rawData[alphaIndex] > 100) {

            for (int row = 1; row <= featherDepth; row++) {
                if (testBorderLayer((long)alphaIndex,
                                    rawData,
                                    (long)rawDataCount,
                                    (long)width,
                                    (long)height,
                                    row)) {

                    int destinationAlpha = 255 / (featherDepth+1) * (row + 1);
                    double alphaDiv =  (double)destinationAlpha / (double)rawData[alphaIndex];

                    rawData[alphaIndex] = destinationAlpha;
                    rawData[alphaIndex-1] = (double)rawData[alphaIndex-1] * alphaDiv;
                    rawData[alphaIndex-2] = (double)rawData[alphaIndex-2] * alphaDiv;
                    rawData[alphaIndex-3] = (double)rawData[alphaIndex-3] * alphaDiv;

//                    switch (row) {
//                        case 1:
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-1] = 255;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-2] = 0;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-3] = 0;
//                            break;
//                        case 2:
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-1] = 0;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-2] = 255;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-3] = 0;
//                            break;
//                        case 3:
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-1] = 0;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-2] = 0;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-3] = 255;
//                            break;
//                        case 4:
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-1] = 127;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-2] = 127;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-3] = 0;
//                            break;
//                        case 5:
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-1] = 127;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-2] = 0;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-3] = 127;
//                        case 6:
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-1] = 0;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-2] = 127;
//                            rawData[alphaIndex-3] = 127;
//                            break;
//                        default:
//                            break;
//                    }

                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }


    CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage scale:[self scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    CGImageRelease(newCGImage);

    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(rawData);

    return result;
}


//==============================================================================


bool testBorderLayer(long byteIndex,
                     unsigned char *imageData,
                     long dataSize,
                     long pWidth,
                     long pHeight,
                     int border) {


    int width = border * 2 + 1;
    int height = width - 2;

    // run thru border pixels
    // |-|
    // | |
    // |-|

    //top,bot - hor
    for (int i = 1; i < width - 1; i++) {


        long topIndex = byteIndex + 4 * ( - border * pWidth - border + i);
        long botIndex = byteIndex + 4 * ( border * pWidth - border + i);

        long destColl = byteIndex/4 % pWidth - border + i;

        if (destColl > 1 && destColl < pWidth) {
            if (testPoint(topIndex, imageData, dataSize) ||
                testPoint(botIndex, imageData, dataSize)) {
                return true;
            }

        }

    }


    //left,right - ver
    if (byteIndex / 4 % pWidth < pWidth - border - 1) {
        for (int k = 0; k < height; k++) {
            long rightIndex = byteIndex + 4 * ( border - (border) * pWidth + pWidth * k);

            if (testPoint(rightIndex, imageData, dataSize)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (byteIndex / 4 % pWidth > border) {

        for (int k = 0; k < height; k++) {
            long leftIndex = byteIndex + 4 * ( - border - (border) * pWidth + pWidth * k);

            if (testPoint(leftIndex, imageData, dataSize)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}


//==============================================================================


bool testPoint(long pointIndex, unsigned char *imageData, long dataSize) {
    if (pointIndex >= 0 && pointIndex < dataSize * 4 - 1 &&
        imageData[pointIndex] < 30) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//==============================================================================
```

Sorry for rare commenting ;)

Comment: Thanks for putting up, Can you explain your code how it works?

Comment: Code looks for border where transparent(alpha channel < 30) and opaque pixels meet. Imagine this pixel  situation: p1(alpha=0) - p2(alpha=0) - p3(alpha=255) - p4(alpha=255) - p5(alpha=255) - p6(alpha=255).
and FeatherDepth = 3.
Result will be: p1(alpha=0) - p2(alpha=0) - p3(alpha=255/3) - p4(alpha=255/3*2) - p5(alpha=255) -

Comment: This was Purpose of the code, It finds this "border" by running thru all pixels and if current pixel is opaque and neighbor pixel is transparent, it means this is border pixel and sets alpha to 255/depth.
If neighbor pixels ar opaque, but if neighbors of neighbor pixels are(at least one) transparent this means, current pixel is second pixel from border and it's alpha is set to 255/depth*2 and so on.

Comment: if you uncomment the switch statement, you'll see colored borders, i was using it for debugging.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you for contributing! Can I use it in my project? If so what's the license for it?

Comment: Also check the question I asked: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362263/ios-and-android-algorithm-or-library-for-feathering-edges-of-the-images-similar

Comment: Just copy and paste it :))

Comment: Okay so as you said I made a class extention UIImage+FeatheringImage.m and included your code in the implementation file and then created a uiimage * featheredImage = self.img and then did [featheredImage featherImageWithDepth:3]; but it didnt do any feather effect on my image at all :( what did i do wrong? are you sure your code works correctly? @zurakach Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show me the code?
This code was working fine. 3 is to0 small, try 10 to make sure you are getting the edited image.

Comment: @zurakach can you explain your code? i implement this code but no feather shadow effect apply in my image.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at this CIFilter list put out by apple, they got some pretty decent filters.

- [/reference/CoreImageFilterReference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-DontLinkElementID_161)

And also check out GPUImage.

- https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: Can you suggest which filter should I use?

Comment: CISpotLight might be what your looking for.