# How to achieve real feather/fade effect on a UIImage which is cropped by a UIBezierpath, without using gradient colors or shadows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have a `UIBezierPath` which crops part of an `UIImage` and then I want to apply feather/fade effect starting from bezierpath towards inside in Objective-C but I dont want to use any gradient color or shadow or any tricks like that. I want the actual image's alpha in its borders, go from 100% to 0%. I've searched a lot but non of the solutions like this one:

- [iOS: Feather with glow/shadow effect on uiimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899995/ios-feather-with-glow-shadow-effect-on-uiimage)
- [iOS and Android Algorithm or library for feathering edges of the images similar to photoshop's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362263/ios-and-android-algorithm-or-library-for-feathering-edges-of-the-images-similar)

has worked for me yet. The result that I want is similar to the image below. How can I achieve this? Any help is much appreciated.[image]

Comment: You can use a mask layer to help you with this. You will need to create a  `CAGradientLayer`  that is black outside the circle and white inside the circle. Then you can set that gradient layer to your view's `layer.mask` property.

Comment: I just updated the picture for the question maybe it explains what i want better.

Comment: I don't want to use gradients and shadows. I want it to actually fade to nothing starting from the bezierpath. @keithbhunter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is playground showing how to do it.  I felt the shadow blur was too weak so I used Core Image's gaussian blur instead.  I thought core image is supposed to be faster these days, but it still seems pretty bad; not sure if its the play ground or not. Try [GPU Image](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) if it needs to be faster.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport        
let image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: imageView.center, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 0.5, clockwise: true).cgPath
let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.path = path
shape.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
let shapeImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageView.frame.size).image { context in
    shape.render(in: context.cgContext)
}
let shapeCimage = CIImage(image: shapeImage)
let gaussianBlurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
gaussianBlurFilter.setValue(shapeCimage, forKey: "inputImage")
gaussianBlurFilter.setValue(NSNumber(value: 5), forKey: "inputRadius")
let blurredImage = UIImage(ciImage: gaussianBlurFilter.value(forKey: "outputImage") as! CIImage)
let maskView = UIImageView(image: blurredImage)
maskView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
maskView.frame = imageView.frame
imageView.mask = maskView

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
```

Comment: I've never used CI in a playground, but while it's noticeably slow in the simulator, it operates very fast on pretty much any iOS device. Just be sure to use a GLKView instead of a UIImageView. (I think the reason the simulator is slow is because it isn't using the Mac GPU like an iOS device does.

Comment: I undersand but I really don't want to use playground and I'm writing my code in objective c wihtout using playground, will it still be slow wihtout using playground? @dfd

Comment: I'll just say this: don't trust the simulator. Test on a real device. Also, the language used should not make any impact on performance.

Comment: And btw you have used a colored layer to be faded/blurred into another layer, I need two images to be faded/blured into eachother not colored layers because you have filled the shape with color ` shape.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor` and I want the shape to contain image, not color. will it still work? How? Thanks. @josh Homann

Comment: Did you run the code???  The mask only uses the alpha channel; the color is irrelevant so long as it is opaque. I chose red to make it obvious when viewing the intermediate result. its also the photoshop quick mask color.

Comment: I couldn't correctly write it in Objective -c using CGContext, is there any way you could write it using Obj - C too? I'd be so thankful. @JoshHomann

Comment: post your code in another questions and i will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need a gradient for this you can use a dropShadow with a white color to achieve this effect.  You will need two separate views.  One view should have its layer.mask set to a CAShapeLayer equal to the UIBezierPath.cgPath.  You have to also turn on maskToBounds for this to work.  Unfortunately maskToBounds will prevent the shadow from drawing on this layer because the shadow is outside of the bounds, which is why you need a second view.  It should have a layer = a CAShapeLayer with the same path, and a dropShadow applied with white.

Comment: Thank you I will try this approach But the bezierpath will be different every time, i need a dynamic solution because the bezierpath is a closed path  will be drawn by the user and will be different every time. Will it work dynamically?

Comment: Yes, all you have to do is update the layer with the new path.  typically I just do this in layoutSubviews, sicne I want the path to scale and fill the view as it resizes.  Then if you need to invalidate the view you can just call setNeedsLayout and it will recalculate itself and update the path.

Comment: Thanks very much I will try it asap and if it works of course ill check the answer tick up there for you. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: but there's one problem, I want  the fade effect, not a shadow, because the layers theres no white, actually theres nothing in the place you see as white) because I've cropped it out and i only want to apply a fade effect not a shadow with white color

Comment: If you are after a feathering effect like in photoshop, I am not sure that there is a cheap way to achieve this.  Conceptually what you want to do is still mask the image, but for the faded part you want to render the shadow and then apply this as an alpha mask.  There is an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899995/ios-feather-with-glow-shadow-effect-on-uiimage  I feel like this would be better done with GPU Image or CIImage, but I can't think of an easy way to do it without writing a custom shader.  If I think of something else i will update the answer.

Comment: actually i am over complicating it.  Just render the shadow as an image then apply the shadow image as a mask to the original image.  composite the alpha masked image with the shape masked image and you are done.

Comment: Actually as I said, there's no shadow made out of color, actually it is similar to the feathering effect in the photoshop, I just want to apply an actual fading effect on the image itself, will it be possible with the last approach you explained? Again thank you. Iupdated the picture of the question.

Comment: Yes if you mask the image with a shape you will get the solid portion.  If you render the shadow of that shape to an image and then use that image as a mask on your original image, you will get the feathered portion.  Combining the solid portion and the feather portion will give you the effect you are looking for.

Comment: I want to feather two actual pictures (not simple solo colored layers) to eachother without using any colored shadows, no matter what I've done in these two days, it didnt work :( would you share the code to see what should i exactly do without using any colored shadows? I'd totally appreciate it. @josh Homann

Answer (score 0):

So here is the Objective-c version I used which worked much better than I expected. There is an important thing to consider. In my personal experience, I got the best Fade/Feather effect when the value for @inputRadius was between 6-8, even though the documentation says it can be between 1-10, you can basically set higher values than 10 too but if you want to get the best Edge feathering result, 6-8 is the best. Here's my code.

```
 UIImage* Img =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];
    UIImageView * imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:Img];
    [imageview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, Img.size.width, Img.size.height)];

    UIBezierPath * newPath = //Your Custom drawn bezierpath.
    newPath.lineWidth = 2;
    CAShapeLayer*shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
    shapeLayer.path=newPath.CGPath;
    [shapeLayer setFillColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    [shapeLayer fillColor];

    UIGraphicsImageRenderer * renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc] initWithSize:Img.size];
    UIImage *shapeImage = [renderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext * _Nonnull context){
        [shapeLayer renderInContext: context.CGContext];}];

    CIImage * shapeCimage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:shapeImage];
    CIFilter * gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:shapeCimage forKey: @"inputImage"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:@8 forKey:@"inputRadius"];

    CIImage * blurredCIImage = [gaussianBlurFilter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    UIImage * blurredImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:blurredCIImage];

    UIImageView *maskedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:blurredImage];
    maskedImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    maskedImageView.frame = imageview.frame;
    imageview.layer.mask=maskedImageView.layer;

    [self.view addSubview:imageview];
```